# Waiting for update signal from WDS

Tags: vue.js

I am currently trying to create a login page using Twitter authentication for my Vue.js application. I have been following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@okpalachuks/twitter-authentication-with-vue-vuex-and-firebase-1f65f68dc0b0) and this [code](https://github.com/chuks-o/twitterauth). Whenever I run my project, I get

> [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...

Any ideas how I can overcome this WDS error? Thank you.

[This is the error I receive in the browser's console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrsuT.png)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...` is not an error. HMR: Hot Module Reload. WDS: Webpack Dev Server. This is just saying it's ready to refresh when you save a file so you don't need to manually refresh.

The actual error appears to be present because you're using the `<template>` tag somewhere, but you've got the `runtimeCompiler` option set to `false` in your vue.config.js, or it's not present. So in your vue.config.js, set it to true, or add the option and set it to true.

Documentation source: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler

Comment: thanks for the reply! I was thinking this. Where can I find the vue.config.js? Is it in node modules somewhere? I am new to this apologies

Comment: No problem. From that same link, justt at the top of the page: "vue.config.js is an optional config file that will be automatically loaded by @vue/cli-service if it's present in your project root (next to package.json). You can also use the vue field in package.json, but do note in that case you will be limited to JSON-compatible values only."

Answer (score 0):

This is very weird thing, I also had this error but when I remove "form" tag and replaced it with "div", It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the form. Add `$event` attribute to your tag form and `e.preventDefault();` to your method.

something like:

```
    <form action="" @submit="sendForm($event)">
    ....
    </form>
    <script>
    sendForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("reload form")
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an infinite loop at the start of the app as it had some bugs with authentication checks, preventing the Vue app to start correctly.